# How to implement setUp and tearDown functions in Lua before and after testcase

Tags: unit-testing, testing, lua, automation

I am trying to write test cases in lua. I want to do some setUp before executing test cases and tearDown after executing the test cases. How would I able to acheive in LUA. Does lua supports this?

myFirstLuaTesting.lua

```
function setUp() #Should be executed first
    --setup the testcase

function testSample1() #Should be executed after setup
    --execute assertions in test case
function testSample1() #Should be executed after setup
    --execute assertions in test case

function tearDown() #Should be executed last after testcases executed
    --tearDown the testcase
```

I am using lunatest framework to run the test case

```
lunatest.suite("myFirstLuaTesting")
lunatest.run()
```

Comment: before writing your own, check out http://lua-users.org/wiki/UnitTesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with functions called "setup", "teardown", "suite_setup" and "suite_teardown". The ones you have (setUp and tearDown) will not be found by the test driver.